# Stored lambda function calls are very slow - fix or workaround?

Tags: c++11, lambda

In an attempt to make a more usable version of the code I wrote for an answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42850325/parallel-for-loop-in-c/42851065), I used a lambda function to process an individual unit. This is a work in progress. I've got the "client" syntax looking pretty nice:

```
// for loop split into 4 threads, calling doThing for each index
parloop(4, 0, 100000000, [](int i) { doThing(i); });
```

However, I have an issue. Whenever I call the saved lambda, it takes up a *ton* of CPU time. doThing itself is an empty stub. If I just comment out the internal call to the lambda, then the speed returns to normal (4 times speedup for 4 threads). I'm using std::function to save the reference to the lambda.

My question is - Is there some better way that the stl library internally manages lambdas for large sets of data, that I haven't come across?

```
struct parloop
{
public:
    std::vector<std::thread> myThreads;
    int numThreads, rangeStart, rangeEnd;
    std::function<void (int)> lambda;

    parloop(int _numThreads, int _rangeStart, int _rangeEnd, std::function<void(int)> _lambda) //
        : numThreads(_numThreads), rangeStart(_rangeStart), rangeEnd(_rangeEnd), lambda(_lambda) //
    {
        init();
        exit();
    }

    void init()
    {
        myThreads.resize(numThreads);

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i)
        {
            myThreads[i] = std::thread(myThreadFunction, this, chunkStart(i), chunkEnd(i));
        }
    }

    void exit()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i)
        {
            myThreads[i].join();
        }
    }

    int rangeJump()
    {
        return ceil(float(rangeEnd - rangeStart) / float(numThreads));
    }

    int chunkStart(int i)
    {
        return rangeJump() * i;
    }

    int chunkEnd(int i)
    {
        return std::min(rangeJump() * (i + 1) - 1, rangeEnd);
    }

    static void myThreadFunction(parloop *self, int start, int end) //
    {
        std::function<void(int)> lambda = self->lambda;
        // we're just going to loop through the numbers and print them out
        for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
        {
            lambda(i); // commenting this out speeds things up back to normal
        }
    }

};

void doThing(int i) // "payload" of the lambda function
{
}

int main()
{
    auto start = timer.now();
    auto stop = timer.now();


    // run 4 trials of each number of threads
    for (int x = 1; x <= 4; ++x)
    {
        // test between 1-8 threads
        for (int numThreads = 1; numThreads <= 8; ++numThreads)
        {
            start = timer.now();

            // this is the line of code which calls doThing in the loop

            parloop(numThreads, 0, 100000000, [](int i) { doThing(i); });

            stop = timer.now();

            cout << numThreads << " Time = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(stop - start).count() / 1000000.0f << " ms\n";
            //cout << "\t\tsimple list, time was " << deltaTime2 / 1000000.0f << " ms\n";
        }
    }

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you use modern c++ features like `auto` and `std::thread` but then you go and have double raw pointers and explicit `new` calls? Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: i don't need the features of std::vector here at all, so why have the higher overhead? It would take just as much time to write that as what I did write.

Comment: vector has negligible overhead. You don't need pointers to threads to join them.

Comment: @JasonLang umm.. vector has near 0-overhead. No, it would take you significantly less to write the vector solution, and most importantly you would get out of the box RAII correct behavior. The explicit new/delete version has bugs: You are missing `cpy ctor`, `cpy assign` and in case anything throws you have mem leak. Read on the rule of 0/3/5

Comment: @JasonLang Maybe it would take as much time, but the other solution would be correct.

Comment: Did you enabled compiler optimizations? My suspicion is you didn't...

Comment: @bolvov, thanks it looks like there were some issues with the VS2015 profiles on this computer, and I fixed those up. I've also made the small changes to convert the code over to use vectors if you think that will avoid memory leaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using `std::function` to save the reference to the lambda.

That's one possible problem, as `std::function` is **not** a zero-runtime-cost abstraction. It is a type-erased wrapper that has a `virtual`-call like cost when invoking `operator()` and could also potentially heap-allocate *(which could mean a cache-miss per call)*.

If you want to store your lambda in such a way that does not introduce additional overhead and that allows the compiler to *inline* it, you should use a template parameter. This is not always possible, but might fit your use case. Example:

```
template <typename TFunction>
struct parloop
{
public:
    std::thread **myThreads;
    int numThreads, rangeStart, rangeEnd;
    TFunction lambda;

parloop(TFunction&& _lambda, 
        int _numThreads, int _rangeStart, int _rangeEnd)
    : lambda(std::move(_lambda)), 
      numThreads(_numThreads), rangeStart(_rangeStart), 
      rangeEnd(_rangeEnd) 
{
    init();
    exit();
}

// ...
```

---

To deduce the type of the lambda, you can use an helper function:

```
template <typename TF, typename... TArgs>
auto make_parloop(TF&& lambda, TArgs&&... xs)
{
    return parloop<std::decay_t<TF>>(
        std::forward<TF>(lambda), std::forward<TArgs>(xs)...);
}
```

Usage:

```
auto p = make_parloop([](int i) { doThing(i); }, 
                      numThreads, 0, 100000000);
```

---

I wrote an article that's related to the subject: 
[**"Passing functions to functions"**](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html)

It contains some benchmarks that show how much assembly is generated for `std::function` compared to a template parameter and other solutions.

Comment: should be std::forward not std::move, as TFunction&& is a deduced context, it can bind to const &

Comment: @Caleth No, `TFunction` is not being deduced in `parloop`'s constructor. It's a parameter of the struct itself.

Comment: ... actually yes, that's true, but it also means you can't call this with an lvalue functor

Comment: @Caleth: yep - the solution is to templatize `parloop`'s constructor with another template parameter and then forward that into `lambda`.

Comment: With this, my call parloop(stuff) is not able to deduce the needed template parameter unless I give it "parloop<std::function<void(int)>>" which completely defeats the purpose because TFunction is the same as before. Is there another way I can deduce the correct type here?

Comment: @JasonLang: edited my question. BTW, you can use `decltype` to get the type of a lambda.

Comment: ok cool, this is all handy to know, I've got your additions working and used decltype to retrieve the typename, it's still the same as std::function<void(int)>. For this particular issue the problem was in fact the compiler it seems, and I have actually gotten the higher speedups by fixing up all the project settings. optimization settings on these machines were all turned off for some reason.

Comment: @JasonLang: great to hear that you solved your issue - note that I measured `std::function` overhead with optimizations enabled in [**this article**: "passing functions to functions"](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html), and it does generate much more assembly than a template parameter or other solutions. The results may interest you.

Comment: thanks, that's a good resource, i got some useful information from that to get a function pointer working instead of the std::function. I tested it with typedefs: "typedef std::function<void(int)> lambdaType;" vs "
typedef void(*lambdaType)(int);" the second one is much much faster.